# Eclipse: Can't add a relative path to a .txt file to a Java application

Tags: java, eclipse, file, csv, tomcat

I have a Java web application (running on Tomcat 9.0 on Linux) that retrieves a message (including a unique 4-letter location code), looks up the code in a CSV file and returns a human-readable location name. For example `CLLK,Clear Lake`.

The application was working well, when I'd loaded the file's absolute path  `/home/beau/eclipse-workspace/pagerfeed/brigades.csv`.

But when I tried to change this to a relative path `pagerfeed/brigades.csv`, the file couldn't be found. Further investigation found that Eclipse was expecting to find the file at `/home/beau/pagerfeed/brigades.csv`, completely ignoring my `eclipse-workspace` folder.

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Additionally, the file is currently just in the project's root directory, which I assume isn't best practice. Considering it will be deployed as a WAR file, is there somewhere better to put this file? (It can be accessible from the address bar.)

The code to load the file (yes it's messy - the commented lines are other methods I've tried that haven't worked properly):

```
// The code that actually gets the file (not working)
Brigade.importBrigadesFromFile("pagerfeed/brigades.csv");

// The code, when it WAS working
Brigade.importBrigadesFromFile("/home/beau/eclipse-workspace/pagerfeed/brigades.csv");

// And my background code to read the file
public Iterable<CSVRecord> read(String file) {              
    Iterable<CSVRecord> records = null;
    try {           
        Reader reader = new FileReader(file);
        // InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
        // InputStream inputStream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(file);
        // BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        records = CSVFormat.DEFAULT.parse(reader);
        System.out.println("Found the CSV file!");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
        String absolutePath = new File("/data/testFile").getAbsolutePath();
        System.out.println("File was not found.");
        System.out.println("Try putting file here: " + absolutePath + ". ");
        fe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Unable to parse the CSV file. Details: ");
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NullPointerException ne) {         
        System.out.println("Could not read file at " + new File("filegoeshere").getAbsolutePath());
        System.out.println("InputStream returned null. Details: ");
        ne.printStackTrace();
    }
    return records;
}
```

Screenshot of my Eclipse path variables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/la3w6.jpg

Comment: Please show your code, show what the user.dir path and where your file is relative to this path. Question: why aren't you getting the information as a a resource and not a file? If you're not writing to it, this the better/safer way.

Comment: Code is up, not at the computer right now but the file is in the PROJECT_LOC directory as per screenshot above, that is, `eclipse-workspace/pagerfeed`. I did try getting it as a resource based on a lot of Googling, but couldn’t get it to work,so changed it back temporarily.

Comment: What is the exact user.dir? And again, why not use resources?

Comment: Create `pagerfeed/brigades.csv` within your classpath, for example, inside `WEB-INF/classes`.